# Updating Django Model After Serialization from DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, scrapyd

I currently have an API endpoint that receives data from the client and kicks of a scrapy crawler job.

The problem is I need to create the Job model instance, kick off the scrapy job, then update the model with the task_id returned by the scrapy job. The model is successfully updated, but the serialized data returned by DRF does not have the updated data.

I need to create the model instance prior to kicking off the job so that the scrapy job has the primary key of the job to update its status and add data as it finishes the job.

I know why JSON response does not have my new data: I am updating the model in the view after DRF has done its work. I cannot edit the serialized data once .save() has been called on the serializer instance.

views.py

```py
class StartJobView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        # map incoming 'id' field to 'client_id'
        request.data['client_id'] = request.data['id']
        serializer = JobSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():

            # create job entry
            serializer.save()
            id = serializer.data.get('id')

            # get pk to pass to spider
            settings = {
                'id': id,
            }

            task_id = scrapyd.schedule('default', 'tester', settings=settings)
            Job.objects.filter(id=id).update(task_id=task_id)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

JSON response:

```
{
    "id": "5f05f555-3214-41e4-81d1-b3915ae3f448",
    "client_id": "8923356a-bc6e-4f17-bbea-bbc8699d308e",
    "task_id": null,
    "created": "2019-08-10T19:01:17.541873Z",
    "status": "not_started",
    "url": "http://brenden.info"
}
```

How do I make the serializer class aware of model updates after I have called the .save() function on the serializer instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that scrapy doesn't wait for the job to be finished. the job is scheduled and will be done in another thread. I'm not sure if there is a callback function built-in scrapy itself but you can do the checking yourself.

You can wait till the status is changed and then do the rest of serializing.

Example:

```
job_reult_check(job_id):
    # It sets the limit for the total checks
    # Here it will be 2 sec
    check_limit = 10
    wait_time = 0.2
    while check_limit > 0:
        # Give the job some time before the check
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)
        if job.status = "done":
            check_limit = 0
        else:
            check_limit -= 1
    return job
```

Call this function before returning the response in your view:

```
class StartJobView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        # map incoming 'id' field to 'client_id'
        request.data['client_id'] = request.data['id']
        serializer = JobSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():

            # create job entry
            serializer.save()
            id = serializer.data.get('id')

            # get pk to pass to spider
            settings = {
                'id': id,
            }

            task_id = scrapyd.schedule('default', 'tester', settings=settings)
            job = Job.objects.filter(id=id).update(task_id=task_id)
            job = job_reult_check(job.pk)

            if job.status = "done":
                 # Job is finished
                 # You need to re-serialize the new instance
                 serializer = JobSerializer(job)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```